# Struggling to get h.264 encoding working for RDP with NVIDIA A2

Tags: graphics-card, remote-desktop, nvidia-graphics-card, encoding

I have a server VM where I have enabled the three group policies:

- Use hardware graphics adapters for all Remote Desktop Services
  sessions
- Prioritize H.264/AVC 444 graphics mode for Remote Desktop Connections
- Configure H.264/AVC hardware encoding for Remote Desktop Connections

This server also has nvidia vGPU enabled with the latest drivers from Nvidia for the A2 card installed and using the q4 profile in vmware esxi. Clients connecting to the VM also have nvidia t1000 cards with the latest studio drivers. When connecting it appears I'm still using remoteFX instead of h.264 according to the event viewer. The server appears to be fully using the graphics card for acceleration within its self with no issue.

Here's a screenshot of the Task Manager showing the Nvidia A2-4Q graphics adapter being recognized:

[image: screenshot of the Task Manager showing the Nvidia A2-4Q graphics adapter being recognized]

Under event 162 in RemoteDesktopServices-RdpCoreTS it shows `The client supports version 0xA0600 of the RDP graphics protocol, client mode: 0, AVC available: 1, Initial profile: 2048`

Event 170 shows `AVC hardware encoder enabled: 1, encoder name is NVIDIA H.264 Encoder MFT`

And finally event 227 shows a few different erorrs:

`'Failed GetConnectionProperty' in CUMRDPConnection::QueryProperty at 2884 err=[0x80004001]`

`'Failed CreateVirtualChannel call on this Connections Stack' in CUMRDPConnection::CreateVirtualChannel at 2498 err=[0xd0000001]`

`'Reverse Connection Listener Name not found.  Default Listener Name will be used.' in CUMRDPProtocolManager::CreateListener at 4156 err=[0x2]`

`'Connection doesn't support logon error redirector' in CUMRDPConnection::GetLogonErrorRedirector at 4179 err=[0x80004001]`

Can anyone point me towards resources for tuning this up to use full hardware acceleration for RDP? It seems like all of microsofts docs stop after enabling h.264 in the group policies.